# What is wrong with my Regex Checking method?

Tags: java, regex

I'm making a Sign-up interface that contains: username, password and confirm password. It must check the regex of the username and the password. But whatever i input, it keeps being wrong

The username[1] use JTextField
The password[1] and confirmPassInput use JPasswordField

```
if ( nameLargeButton.equals("Sign-in")){
      String user = username[1].getText();          

      char[] passChars = password[1].getPassword(); 
      String pass = new String(passChars);          

      char[] cfPassChars = confirmPassInput.getPassword(); 
      String cfPass = new String(cfPassChars);  
      //biểu thức chính quy 
      Pattern reUser = Pattern.compile("^[a-z0-9_-]{5,12}(?!\\\\s)$");  
      Pattern rePass = Pattern.compile("^.{6,}$");             
      if(e.getSource() == largeButton){
      if (reUser.matcher(user).find() && rePass.matcher(pass).find() && pass.equals(cfPass)) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Success", "Thông báo", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
      }
      else if (!reUser.matcher(user).find()){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid Username", "Thông báo", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
        resetLoginDialog();
      }
      else if (!rePass.matcher(pass).find()){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid Password", "Thông báo", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
      } 
      else {
        // Mật khẩu không hợp lệ, hiển thị thông báo
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid", "Thông báo", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
      }
    }
    }
```

I think that when i press the "Sign-in" button, it will compare the text from "username[1]" and "password[1]" to "reUser" and "rePass"

```
username: Bababa
password: 123qwerty
confirm password: 123qwerty
```

the input above should be right but it always show "Invalid Username"
What do I do wrong ?

Comment: Your user regex doesn't match uppercase letters and in your example you are passing **B**ababa. Also, why do you need negative lookahead?

Answer (score 2):

According to this pattern `^[a-z0-9_-]{5,12}(?!\\\\s)$`, your username `Bababa` doesn't match because it contains a capital letter.

Pattern matching is case-sensitive. In your pattern, you've only included `a-z`, which are lowercase letters.

To include upper-case letters, you need to add `A-Z` to your pattern. So change your pattern to `^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{5,12}(?!\\\\s)$`.

Comment: Note also that `(?!\\\\s)` is totally useless.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte I think that would mean don't allow any space?

Comment: You don't need to check if there's a space (or any other character) at the end of the string.